# How can I find the entire hull of a 3D object without holes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, convex-hull, mplot3d

I have a cloud of 8 nodes which form a prism. I need the Information which node belongs to which side of the prism. It might be, that a side of the prism is plane, but this is not always the case.

So I thought I can search for triangles with ConvexHull and then find coplanar triangles with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098466/plot-3d-convex-closed-regions-in-matplot-lib/49115448#49115448) from . This worked pretty well for a symmetric prism (like a cuboid) but in my case the object has no rectangular edges at all. When transferring the code to my problem, unfortunately always "holes" remain in the surface.

Here is my code so far.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
from sympy import Plane, Point3D
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import scipy as sp

nodes = np.array([[5.05563104322024e+04, 9.86881840921214e+04, -1.86894465727364e+03], [5.05703988843260e+04, 9.86813866643775e+04, -2.17336823588979e+03], [5.02542761707438e+04, 9.87087037212873e+04, -1.87234751337548e+03], [5.05535885714918e+04, 9.90000078125000e+04, -1.88856455463216e+03], [5.02534400234038e+04, 9.86956918140383e+04, -2.16834889960677e+03], [5.02542854985772e+04, 9.90000078125000e+04, -1.86873609902935e+03], [5.05494853841027e+04, 9.90000078125000e+04, -2.20374533059710e+03], [5.02533554687500e+04, 9.90000078125000e+04, -2.19881323242188e+03]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.dist=10
ax.azim=30
ax.elev=30
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

verts = zip(*nodes)

ax.plot(verts[0], verts[1], verts[2], 'bo')
hull = ConvexHull(nodes)
faces = hull.simplices

triangles = []
for i in hull.simplices:
    i = np.append(i, i[0])
    plt.plot(nodes[i,0], nodes[i,1], nodes[i,2])

for j in faces:
    tri = [(nodes[j[0], 0], nodes[j[0], 1], nodes[j[0], 2]), (nodes[j[1], 0], nodes[j[1], 1], nodes[j[1], 2]), (nodes[j[2], 0], nodes[j[2], 1], nodes[j[2], 2])]
    triangles.append(tri)

def simplify(triangles):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(len(triangles)))
    for ii, a in enumerate(triangles):
        for jj, b in enumerate(triangles):
            if (ii < jj): 
                if is_adjacent(a, b):
                    if is_coplanar(a, b, np.pi / 180.):
                        G.add_edge(ii,jj)
    components = list(nx.connected_components(G))
    simplified = [set(flatten(triangles[index] for index in component)) for component in components]
    reordered = [reorder(face) for face in simplified]
    return reordered

def is_adjacent(a, b):
    return len(set(a) & set(b))

def is_coplanar(a, b, tolerance_in_radians=0):
    a1, a2, a3 = a
    b1, b2, b3 = b
    plane_a = Plane(Point3D(a1), Point3D(a2), Point3D(a3))
    plane_b = Plane(Point3D(b1), Point3D(b2), Point3D(b3))
    if not tolerance_in_radians: # only accept exact results
        return plane_a.is_coplanar(plane_b)
    else:
        angle = plane_a.angle_between(plane_b).evalf()
        angle %= np.pi # make sure that angle is between 0 and np.pi
        return (angle - tolerance_in_radians <= 0.) or \
            ((np.pi - angle) - tolerance_in_radians <= 0.)

flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def reorder(vertices):
    if len(vertices) <= 3: 
        return vertices
    else:
        reordered = [vertices.pop()]
        vertices = list(vertices)
        while len(vertices) > 1:
            idx = np.argmin(get_distance(reordered[-1], vertices))
            v = vertices.pop(idx)
            reordered.append(v)
        reordered += vertices
        return reordered

def get_distance(v1, v2):
    v2 = np.array(list(v2))
    difference = v2 - v1
    ssd = np.sum(difference**2, axis=1)
    return np.sqrt(ssd)

new_faces = simplify(triangles)

for sq in new_faces:
    f = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([sq])
    f.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3)))
    f.set_edgecolor('k')
    f.set_alpha(0.1)
    ax.add_collection3d(f)

plt.show()
```

---

As you can see in the screenshot below I have a hole at the top of my prism. Do you know how I can fix this and get all triangles or quadrangles of the hull of my prism?

Thank you!

---

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Edit:
I made some changes to my code (see below), so now all triangles/quadrangles are plottet seperatly and all faces are found. Could it be a plotting bug?

```py
# verts = zip(*nodes)
verts = nodes.T

hull = ConvexHull(nodes, incremental=True)
faces = hull.simplices

triangles = []
for i in hull.simplices:
    i = np.append(i, i[0])
    plt.plot(nodes[i,0], nodes[i,1], nodes[i,2])

for j in faces:
    tri = [(nodes[j[0], 0], nodes[j[0], 1], nodes[j[0], 2]), (nodes[j[1], 0], nodes[j[1], 1], nodes[j[1], 2]), (nodes[j[2], 0], nodes[j[2], 1], nodes[j[2], 2])]
    triangles.append(tri)


new_faces = simplify(triangles)

for sq in new_faces:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.plot(verts[0], verts[1], verts[2], 'bo')
    ax.dist=10
    ax.azim=110
    ax.elev=30
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    f = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([sq])
    f.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3)))
    f.set_edgecolor('k')
    # f.set_alpha(0.1)
    ax.add_collection3d(f)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some tolerance criteria for your coplanarity.

In your case just set the `tolerance_in_radians` keyword in the function `is_coplanar(a, b, tolerance_in_radians=0)` to an appropriate value.

Else:

- calculate the surface normals, maybe your convex hull already returns them.
  It should return triangles with a fixed order (clockwise, counter-clockwise)
- calculate the centroid of the nodes
- as a check calculate if the surface normals are pointing away from the centroid
- calculate the angle between the surface normals
- for angles lower than maybe 0.5 ° triangles are "co-planar" enough for your case

Comment: The first impression was that to increase my tolerance angle will solve my problem, but if I take another node-cloud this will make it worse as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/L9azQ33) with these nodes:

nodes = np.array([[1.188e+04, 6.838e+04, -2.636e+02], [1.196e+04, 6.783e+04, -2.503e+02], [1.197e+04, 6.787e+04, -2.1e+02], [1.187e+04, 6.84e+04, -2.09e+02], [1.128e+04, 6.827e+04, -2.409e+02], [1.137e+04, 6.77e+04, -2.36e+02], [1.135e+04, 6.782e+04, -2.109e+02], [1.127e+04, 6.838e+04, -2.099e+02]])

Comment: Do you know the triangles you are putting in? If not, construct an example where you know them. Then check with the `is_planar()` function which triangles fail and why, e.g. what are the angles between the surface normals or the planes. Easiest way: just add a `print()` if a triangle fails but should not according to the known geometry you put in.

Comment: Could it be that this a plotting bug? Because if I plot each triangle individually, all faces will be found correctly. I will add the changes in my code in the question.

Comment: Could be. Matplotlib is not very good at 3d plotting, but this should work. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461819/7919597